# OpenApi Generator to generate parameter with @RequestBody as String

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the following OpenApi specs:

```
paths:
  /student:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Student"
      responses:
        204:


components:
  schemas:
    Student:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        school:
          type: string
```

With org.openapitools.generator, it generates a controller with function *like* below

```
void addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
}
```

Is there any way to configure the generator to generate @RequestBody as String?

```
void addStudent(@RequestBody String student) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your response as `text/plain` with `schema: type: string` in your OpenAPI.

Apart from that, you can keep the `Student` schema in your OpenAPI and the generator should generate it as a java class.

```yaml
    paths:
      /ping:
        get:
          responses:
            '200':
              description: OK
              content:
                text/plain:
                  schema:
                    type: string
                    example: pong
```

Read the official docs [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/).

Comment: Not sure if I understood your suggestion. I actually just want the generator to give me the body in raw String format, instead of marshaling it to Student class.

Comment: I think the generator will generate the java code by analyzing the context type in your openapi. For instance, `@RequestBody String student` this is generated because you have, `content: application/json: schema: $ref: "#/components/schemas/Student"` Therefore, I think if you set the content type to text/plain, the generator will generate the method with a string param `void addStudent(@RequestBody String student) {`

Comment: thanks. But actually I'm looking for a way to configuration openapi generator to generate @RequestBody with String for that particular model and without changing the yaml specification.